# WPF App Ignores Input

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mouseevent

Is there away to have a WPF app (intended just to display purposes) ignore all user input and in fact, instruct Windows to send me the events to any items "under it"?

A simple example would to put the text "Hello" across the screen. And even though the text would always be on top, if a window were underneath it, it would receive user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the **AllowTransparency** property to *True* and the **Background** to *Transparent*, it should work.

[» Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/a5e3cbbb-fd07-4343-9b60-6903cdfeca76/)

Comment: I'll experiment with this. Thanks.

Comment: This works partially. When you click in the transparent areas, the touches do go beneath (good). However when you click on your controls (say a white box), the touches are consumed. I'd like all clicks to go beneath.

Comment: Hm... make them transparent too? (Could be done with a global variable you databind to)

Answer (score 0):

You can catch all Mouse & Keyboard inputs with `e.Cancel = true` in each events method.

Thus, all user inputs on your windows wont have any effect.

Comment: It's not just that they shouldn't have any effect, they should have the effect as if the app wasn't running. So if the app is over the start button for example, the start button should still receive the click.